# Detect anomaly users who try to access too often based on the access log

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection, logarithm

Does anyone give me advice for statistically detecting anomaly users who try to log in our website too often?

At first, the idea that came to my mind is to use Spike detection approaches or IQR truncated by min to set lower & upper bounds. However, there is a case that spike detection can't detect that some users constantly log in. e.g) 10 times every 1 min for 5 mins

The log data consists of dateTime in second and user names. For example,

```
2019-08-24 14:52:00 UserA
2019-08-24 14:52:01 UserB
2019-08-24 14:52:01 UserA
2019-08-24 14:52:02 UserC
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe some clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Compute how often each user logs in per time period (say 1 hour). I would expect that value to be between 0 and 1 for the majority of the time. So anything above 1 login would likely be easy to detect